# expo.dev says "[stderr] This command requires Expo CLI. Do you want to install it globally [Y/n]?"

Tags: javascript, android, expo, eas

I can't build my expo app for android, with SDK 47. Typed `eas build --platform android`.
Here's the build screen:
[image]
This shouldn't have happened, I don't know how to solve it. I've been dealing with this for two days, people say eject or prebuild and try it. Makes sense, but it creates new problems with andorid's gradle, any way to avoid this. I thought expo-cli was part of expo build.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I increased SDK version at app.json to  `"sdkVersion": "47.0.0",` from 45.0.0. But I didn't touch expo version at package.json. It was 45 as well. I upgraded my expo to 47, it solved the problem.